# How can I parse the table in this page?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to parse the table with

> id=standings-16548-grid
>
> class=grid with-centered-columns hover

. Unfortunatly when I try it the output shows me like the tr are completely empty. Since I'm new to this language I was wondering if I'm missing something.

Afterwards I'll also scrape the datas from the sheet "form" and not only from the sheet "standings", but I'm trying to do one step at the time.

Below you can find my code.

I already tried with selenium to open a webpage with Firefox. Then I tried to push the button that shows up as soon you open the page to continue to use the website. Finally using BeautfulSoup I tried to parse the table specyfing the ID of the table.

```
'Python3.7'
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/Applications/Python3.7/geckodriver')
driver.get('https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/108/Tournaments/5/Italy-Serie-A')
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
myDynamicElement = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/button").click()

source = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

driver.quit()

table = soup.find('table', {"id":"standings-16548-grid"})
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('tr')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)
```

The output of this code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Gina/PycharmProjects/Prova1/DriverProva/SeleniumScrape.py", line 12, in <module>

    myDynamicElement = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[9]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/button").click()

  File "/Users/Gina/PycharmProjects/Prova1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)

  File "/Users/Gina/PycharmProjects/Prova1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)

  File "/Users/Gina/PycharmProjects/Prova1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "/Users/Gina/PycharmProjects/Prova1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
>   Element  could not be scrolled into
>   view

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that. I'm gonna contact the website and ask about how to get the license if I want to keep parsing their data.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code.It will returns expected output.

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element could not be scrolled into view

To avoid this error use java script executor to click on the element.I have changed the element xpath as well.

> driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/Applications/Python3.7/geckodriver')
driver.get('https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/108/Tournaments/5/Italy-Serie-A')
element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(.,'Continue Using Site')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)
time.sleep(3)
source=driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
driver.quit()

table = soup.find('table', {"id":"standings-16548-grid"})
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

for tr in table_rows[5:len(table_rows)]:
   row = [i.text for i in tr.find_all('td')]
   print(row)
```

### Output

```
['1', 'Juventus', '38', '28', '6', '4', '70', '30', '+40', '90', 'wddldl']
['2', 'Napoli', '38', '24', '7', '7', '74', '36', '+38', '79', 'lwwwwl']
['3', 'Atalanta', '38', '20', '9', '9', '77', '46', '+31', '69', 'wwwwdw']
['4', 'Inter', '38', '20', '9', '9', '57', '33', '+24', '69', 'dddwlw']
['5', 'AC Milan', '38', '19', '11', '8', '55', '36', '+19', '68', 'dlwwww']
['6', 'Roma', '38', '18', '12', '8', '66', '48', '+18', '66', 'dwdwdw']
['7', 'Torino', '38', '16', '15', '7', '52', '37', '+15', '63', 'wwdwlw']
['8', 'Lazio', '38', '17', '8', '13', '56', '46', '+10', '59', 'lwlwdl']
['9', 'Sampdoria', '38', '15', '8', '15', '60', '51', '+9', '53', 'lldldw']
['10', 'Bologna', '38', '11', '11', '16', '48', '56', '-8', '44', 'wwlwdw']
['11', 'Sassuolo', '38', '9', '16', '13', '53', '60', '-7', '43', 'dwdldl']
['12', 'Udinese', '38', '11', '10', '17', '39', '53', '-14', '43', 'dldwww']
['13', 'SPAL 2013', '38', '11', '9', '18', '44', '56', '-12', '42', 'wdwlll']
['14', 'Parma Calcio 1913', '38', '10', '11', '17', '41', '61', '-20', '41', 'dddlwl']
['15', 'Cagliari', '38', '10', '11', '17', '36', '54', '-18', '41', 'wllldl']
['16', 'Fiorentina', '38', '8', '17', '13', '47', '45', '+2', '41', 'llllld']
['17', 'Genoa', '38', '8', '14', '16', '39', '57', '-18', '38', 'lddldd']
['18', 'Empoli', '38', '10', '8', '20', '51', '70', '-19', '38', 'llwwwl']
['19', 'Frosinone', '38', '5', '10', '23', '29', '69', '-40', '25', 'lldlld']
['20', 'Chievo', '38', '2', '14', '22', '25', '75', '-50', '17', 'wdlldd']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, your code works reealy good.
Now I'm trying to bring this data in an excel scheet and I did so importing the csv library, but when I run the code all the data go in the first column and they do not spread throug the other columns. How can I solve this problem?

I added this code:
     for tr in table_rows[5:len(table_rows)]:
   row = [i.text for i in tr.find_all('td')]
   writer.writerow(row)

Comment: If you use pandas data frame you can easily import data into csv file.Check my answer following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478652/scraping-text-in-h3-and-p-tags-using-beautifulsoup-python/56479359#56479359

Comment: Watching on youtube and your answer in another discussion, pandas looks really helpful. I tried to include it in the code but unfortunatly I didn't get the hoped result. I'll keep working on it and if I really can't figure out a way I'll ask help again.

Comment: Can you accept that answer by clicking on holo under down vote button so it turns to green.so that Future reader can use it.

Comment: I got this message: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Anyway I tried to put the table in a dataframe and then in excel but every row still goes in the first cell (A1, B1, C1 ecc.). Is it possible that the reason why is because I have a old version of Excel?

Comment: dear @kunduk, how can I place a dataframe in an excel sheet in a different position from the default?
For example I'd like to print my database in row:10 and column:20. How can I do that?